# How to make a event wait until jQuery flip effect finish?

Tags: jquery

I got a problem, I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

    $('.clsks').mouseenter(function() {

        var ob = $(this);
        var dar = $(this).attr('ids');
        var obj1 = $('#sponsorFlip'+dar);
        var obj2 = $('#sponsorData'+dar);

        obj1.flip({
                direction:'lr',
                speed: 350,
                onBefore: function(){
                    // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden from view with display:none)
                    // into the clicked .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:
                    obj1.html(obj2.html());

                }
            });

            // Setting the flag:
        //obj1.data('flipped',true);

        }).mouseleave(function() { var dar = $(this).attr('ids');
        var obj1 = $('#sponsorFlip'+dar); obj1.revertFlip(); });

});
```

I need make the event mouseenter wait until this jQuery flip finish cuz sometimes if someone mouseenter fast the mouseleave fails cuz 'obj1.html(obj2.html());' over it.

but I only need to make the mouseenter event wait the jQuery flip finish.

Comment: You can't start the flip on mouseenter, but make the mouseenter wait until the flip is done.  That doesn't make any sense.  When you get the mouseenter event, it's already occurred.  What operations do you want to do after the flip is done?  Or, what is the real problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the doc for the flip method: http://lab.smashup.it/flip and add an `onEnd:` function.  Here's an example from that doc:

```
$("#flipbox").flip({
    direction:'tb',
    onBefore: function(){
            console.log('before starting the animation');
    },
    onAnimation: function(){
            console.log('in the middle of the animation');
    },
    onEnd: function(){
            console.log('when the animation has already ended');
    }
})
```

Comment: is there a way to check if the mouse still over a element? if yes i can do it with onEnd callback

Comment: You can get the current mouse position from the mouseenter event and you can see if it's over a specific object by getting that object's position/size and comparing.  I'm unsure what problem you're really trying to solve so don't know how to help more specifically.  Perhaps if you describe the real problem, we could offer better advice.

Comment: You can set a flag at the start of `mouseenter` to indicate that the mouse is in and turn off the flag at `mouseleave`. In your animation's `onEnd()`, you can check if the mouse is still in by checking the value of this flag.